# Bash/expect script to control execution

Tags: linux, bash, shell, expect, execution

I am looking to control the flow of execution of a compiled C program X using bash scripting. The program X only produces text output and I want immediately pause execution when a certain string is printed. After this, I want to switch into bash and execute some commands and then return back into completing X. I have done some reading and testing and only expect/bash scripting seems to meet my needs. However, I am having difficulties achieving my goal.

I have tried *spawning X* within an expect script and then *expect "mystring"* followed by *sending* bash script commands but this only resulted in the bash commands being executed after X terminated.

Does anyone know the approach of achieving this? To clarify, I cannot use gdb in this situation.

```
#!/usr/bin/expect
spawn X
expect "mystring"
send -- "bash command"
```

Comment: show the minimal script you have written

Comment: I have add the minimal script

Comment: There's going to be an unavoidable delay between when X outputs the string and when X is actually paused: the time it takes to detect the string and react to it. I'm assuming your bash commands are intended to modify how X will proceed; are you sure you can pause X in time to accomplish that?

Comment: I believe so. But I will have to try glenn's method first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would spawn a shell instead of spawning X directly. Then you can use the shell to send a SIGSTOP to the program to pause it (unless the program has the capacity to pause when you send something directly to it).

A demo

```tcl
#!/usr/bin/expect -f

spawn bash
send "unset PROMPT_COMMAND; PS1=:\r"    ;# I have a fairly tricky bash prompt
expect -re ":$"

# this stands-in for "X": start a shell that sends stuff to stdout
send {sh -c 'n=1; while [ $n -lt 10 ]; do echo $n; sleep 1; let n=n+1; done'}
send "\r"

# when I see "5", send a Ctrl-Z to suspend the sh process
expect 5 {send \x1a}
expect -re ":$"

# now do some stuff
send "echo hello world\r"
expect -re ":$"
send "echo continuing\r"
expect -re ":$"

# and re-commence "X"
send "fg\r"
expect -re ":$"

# and we're done
send "exit\r"
expect eof
```

and running it:

```
$ expect intr.exp
spawn bash
unset PROMPT_COMMAND; PS1=:
$ unset PROMPT_COMMAND; PS1=:
:sh -c 'n=1; while [ $n -lt 10 ]; do echo $n; sleep 1; let n=n+1; done'
1
2
3
4
5
^Z
[1]+  Stopped                 sh -c 'n=1; while [ $n -lt 10 ]; do echo $n; sleep 1; let n=n+1; done'
:echo hello world
hello world
:echo continuing
continuing
:fg
sh -c 'n=1; while [ $n -lt 10 ]; do echo $n; sleep 1; let n=n+1; done'
6
7
8
9
:exit
exit
```